# How to get height of axis column's ticks in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have an example like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/meysamm22/mghyznco/9/), as you can see in the example cell's height are different and it is an obstacle to calculate for rendering some custom SVGs. Actually, I want to get height of each cell in this block of code (in my real project):

```
  chart: {
      events: {
         load() {
             var ticks = this.yAxis[0].treeGrid.axis.grid.columns[0].ticks;
             for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(ticks).length ; i++){
             
               // I want to get the current tick height here!!
             }
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please analyze and try to use this part of the code:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var ticks = this.yAxis[0].ticks;
            
            for (var i = 0;  i < Object.keys(ticks).length - 1; i++) {
                 let prevTickHeight = ticks[i - 1].mark.d.split(' ')[2],
                         curTickHeight = ticks[i].mark.d.split(' ')[2] - prevTickHeight;

                 console.log(curTickHeight)
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5zkwh2ta/